# How to check if string is blank in tcsh

Tags: shell-script, tcsh

How can I check whether a string is empty in tcsh?

Before you freak out, no I'm not writing shell scripts with tcsh.  I am asking because I want to use this in my .tcshrc file.

Specifically, I want to do the equivalent of this bash code in tcsh:

```
if [[ -z $myVar ]]; then
  echo "the string is blank"
fi
```

Comment: +1 for "before you freak out" to dissuade the religiously opinionated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if ("$myVar" == "") then
  echo "the string is blank"
endif
```

Note that in csh, it is an error to attempt to access an undefined variable. (From a Bourne shell perspective, it's as if `set -u` was always in effect.) To test whether a variable is defined, use `$?myVar`:

```
if (! $?myVar) then
  echo "myVar is undefined"
else
  if ("$myVar" == "") then
    echo "myVar is empty"
  else
    echo "myVar is non-empty"
  endif
endif
```

Note the use of a nested `if`. You can't use `else if` here, because that would cause the `"$myVar" == ""` condition to be parsed even when the first condition is true. If you want to treat the empty and the undefined case in the same way, first set the variable:

```
if (! $?myVar) then
  set myVar=""
endif

if ("$myVar" == "") then
  echo "myVar is empty or was undefined"
else
  echo "myVar is non-empty"
endif
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use test(1). For example:

```
% test -z "$myVar" && echo "the string is blank"
```

or

```
% [ -z "$myVar" ] && echo "the string is blank"
```

Both assume that $myVar is set.

Comment: Why use the external utility `test`? Csh is brain-dead sometimes, but it does have a built-in way to test if a variable is empty.

Comment: I missed the double braces in ops question and though I thought it should work, I figured it wasn't for the op, thus the suggestion to use test. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Gilles: At any rate, you're correct. `test` is not a built-in in `tcsh` like it is in `bash`. No reason to use `test`.

Answer (score 0):

With `tcsh`, you can use `${%var}` construct to check number of characters in variable `var`:

```
if (${%var} == 0) then
  echo 'var is empty'
endif
```