# tcsh: setenv and updating environment variable from script

Tags: tcsh

I have a  script which is supposed to check whether an environment variable exists and if yes update it using an argument read from command line.
due to some limitations I should use tcsh and current running shell is:

```
> echo $shell 
> /bin/tcsh
```

and the script is:

```
#!/bin/tcsh
if test "x$RUNVERSION" == "x"; then
  echo "RUNVERSION is not set!"
  setenv RUNVERSION 1
else
  echo "RUNVERSION is already set!"
  echo "Current RUNVERSION is:" "$RUNVERSION"
  echo "Enter the new RUNVERSION:"
  read arg 
  setenv RUNVERSION $arg
  echo "RUNVERSION:  " "$arg"
fi
```

I tested a simple script with `setenv RUNVERSION 1` and using  `source ../charSCRIPT/run_char.sh`, it works for setting the environment variable when there is no if-else statment and no dynamically reading input.

but having the above full script source does give me `if: Expression Syntax.`
and `sh ../charSCRIPT/run_char.sh` does not update the environment variable.

Comment: tcsh if statement syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799021/tcsh-script-if-statement

Comment: ... also related [How to check if string is blank in tcsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197497/how-to-check-if-string-is-blank-in-tcsh)

Comment: changing the script according to above links does not help.

Comment: `sh ../charSCRIPT/run_char.sh` uses sh. Since it's now a tcsh script, you need to run `tcsh ../charSCRIPT/run_char.sh`

Comment: I changed sh to tcsh and ran the script with `if-endif`. also changed `read arg` to `set arg=$<` still RUNVERSION doesn't get its update value when using `setenv RUNVER $arg`

Comment: Please edit your question to show the complete version of your current  script and the command you use to run it.